# Rails Take all actions in the controllers in area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my rails application I add an "api" area with controllers

In the route.rb file
I add the area

```
namespace :api do
   #get "dashboard/sales_rate"
  end
```

The controllers Class:

```
class Api::DashboardController < Api::ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def user_service
    render :json => {"user_id" => current_user.id}
  end
```

The Path is:
`app/controllers/api/dashboard_controller`

My question is if I can that the route take all action

for example /api/dashboard/user_service
and I will not add for each route row on the route.rb page

`/api/{controller_under_api_namespace}/{action}`

Comment: You could use the old `/dashboard/:action` syntax or whatever it is. Arguably it's a better idea to add restful routes for those, though.

Comment: Is there a UserService resource? It's unclear what you want to apply restful routes to.

Comment: No its not restful routes its many action with specific names
I try all this option with no success
 namespace :api do
     #match '/dashboard/:action'
     match '/dashboard/(:action(/:id))'

     #match '/dashboard(/:action(/:id))'
  end

Answer (score 0):

You can do with some meta programming sprinkle!

```
Api.constants.each |c|
  c.action_methods.each do |action|
    get [c.controller_name, action].join('/')
  end
end
```

This method limits only to `GET` request. You can overcome it with RESTful routing.

```
Api.constants.each |c|
  resources c.controller_name.to_sym
end
```

Hope, that helps. :)

Comment: Sorry but I am not a rails professional, where I need to write this code, and second if i write the controller I can get all the actions?

Comment: It'll go in `routes.rb` file inside `namespace :api` line.

Yes first method will take care of all actions from the controllers. But it'll be only `GET` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I try add the code on the route.rb file
[image]

and I got this error

[image]

This is my file
[image]

But before trying to fix this part of code, I want to know if it's can change the performance or the calls to those pages?

If it not good for the performance I leave this option.